# CURL not downloading from a URL and no error message

Tags: ubuntu

This should be a simple download and the URL does work. I can download in a browser, but CURL does not download the file and does not display an error.

```
curl https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/releases/download/v6.18.1/xmrig-6.18.1-focal-x64.tar.gz
```

Any help appreciated.

Kerry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running with `curl --verbose` shows that you're receiving a `Location:` redirect instruction. By default `curl` does not follow redirects - you have to enable it. (See `man curl` for this.)

```
curl --location https://…
```

You'll then get told that "*Binary output can mess up your terminal*" and you'll be advised to use `--output` either to confirm writing to *stdout* or to send the output to a file.

```
curl --location --output xmrig-6.18.1-focal-x64.tar.gz https://…
```

Comment: In reading through the verbose response it might be that GITHUB is using Amazon S3 for storage. Would curl see this as a redirect?

Comment: that last command worked perfectly. Thank you so much for the lesson :)

Comment: @KerryA, "_it might be that GITHUB is using Amazon S3 for storage_" - the redirect is presented as an HTTP `Location:` header. If you get one of these you have to tell `curl` to follow it